# how WM_SYSCHAR is produced?

Tags: c++, windows

Why only the ALT + CHAR can create a WM_SYSCHAR?  how about CTRL SHIFT, thay aren's belong to system's key ?

i had read API, but not quite understand..Thank you..

Comment: Alt is defined as the "system " key. Any "system" things you see involve it. Like `WS_SYSMENU`, you can use alt to bring it up (alt-space). Control and shift would be modifier keys.

Comment: You are so fast, i see, thank you! Aha... then the result is the same between ALT and  modifier, they can execute command, so, what is difference?

Comment: I'm not fully sure on the difference, I just know alt is the one used in relation to system things. True you can make shortcuts with ctrl+alt, or ctrl+shift to the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of system keys:

```
ALT + any key
F10
```

F10 activates the menu bar of a window while `ALT + some key` activates a system command used by the operating system. All other key strokes are considered non-system keys.

For a detailed explanation, [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg153546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).